# iOS keyboard missing keys

Tags: ios, ipad

[image]

Occasionally when a user pulls up our app and attempts to type in a text field, the keyboard looks like this. I have pulled the logs from the device and can't find anything unusual. The ipad is running 10.3.3. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This seems like a bug with the keyboard and likely has to do nothing with your app.

Comment: You're probably right, but it's still causing problems for us. I was hoping someone might know more about it.